# Why earth pin in plug is larger than the other pin?

Tags: electric-machine

Why main line pin is not bigger ,the work of main line pin is more important than earth line?
And the flow of electricity is also pass through main line and neutral pin then why earth pin is larger than the other pin?

Comment: Which particular plug are you talking about?

Comment: Used in home appliances.

Comment: South Africa? UK? India? USA?

Comment: It is not AC frequency ,varies with country to country as I know...In India?

Comment: Even in electronics, the ground pin is longer than the hot pin because it's wise to ground your connection first before hot wire gets plugged in. Imagine if opposite was true. What do you think that would do to your connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally the ground pin is a bit longer and can carry more current than the other pins because it's more important in case of a failure of insulation in the device for the ground connection to remain connected long enough for the fuse or circuit breaker to open the circuit.

It's also typically longer so it makes contact first and you cannot have a situation with hot connected and no ground. Of course in normal operation it carries no current.

Sometimes, particularly when the ground is not there, the other pins are asymmetrical so that the hot and neutral cannot be easily swapped. I don't believe that applies to standard Indian plugs, which are a triangle arrangement of round pins, similar to some South African plugs.

Images from [here](https://www.indiaquickfacts.com/content/india-electricity-electrical-plugs-converters-electric-sockets-electric-adapters):

[image]

As Jasen points out, in every design of mains plug I've seen the size and shape of the ground plug is such that it cannot be inserted into either of the other holes. For example, the British BS 1363 plug has a ground pin that is about 8mm wide vs 6.5mm for the power pins.

Comment: I think this is prefect answer.

Comment: it also makes it impossible to plug the earth pin into one of the live holes,